# ::before in css is messing up paragraph indentation

Tags: html, css, indentation

I am drawing up a list of stuffs and when the item has a long description, the text is returning to a new line which sticks to the left, whereas in the first line, i'm using a ::before {content: counter}

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li>Short description</li>
<li>Second item</li>
<li>This stuff is the third element which has a very long text. So it is diplayed in several lines and the result is awful!</li>
</ul>
```

Fichier CSS

```
li::before {margin-left:50px; margin-right:20px; counter-increment: section; content: counter(section) ". ";}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need a margin on only the `::before` pseudoelement instead of just putting a margin on the entire `ul`? What is the final result going to look like? Also, if you just want the text to never wrap, you can use `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul`.

Comment: An option is to add a negative `text-indent` value for your `ul`. Not sure how cross browser friendly that would be, especially with IE.

Comment: Here a link where you can understand what I mean
[link] (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvYWLZ)

Comment: Try this then
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpgEqZ

Comment: It worked fine @AlexanderYW, I even optimized the code [link] (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVNRgR) but I still have no explanation about how the first css code was computed!